# Installing GIT within MSYS2 on Windows 11

Tags: git, gstreamer, msys2

I am trying to complile GStreamer on windows using Cerbero however when finalising the install of this it tell me:

***** Error running 'bootstrap' command:
Configuration Error: git is configured to use automatic line endings conversion. Please change that by running:
`git config --global core.autocrlf false` inside the MSYS shell

I tried to put this into MSYS2 however Git isn't installed, I have followed the guide here to install Git:

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Install-inside-MSYS2-proper

However I am faced with this error?

domin@ASUS_Laptop MSYS ~
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-git
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-git-2.44.0.rc1.windows.1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-git-2.44.0.rc1.windows.1-1

Total Installed Size:  50.17 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                          [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                        [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                             [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                       [##################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                                     [##################################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-git                                                                                                 [##################################################################################] 100%
/tmp/alpm_qelaGb/.INSTALL: line 2: die: command not found
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
error: command (/usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash -c . /tmp/alpm_qelaGb/.INSTALL; post_upgrade 2.44.0.rc1.windows.1-1 2.44.0.rc1.windows.1-1 !) failed to execute correctly

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I have tried using different servers etc.

So I have went back over the guide and I think my problem is when running

pacman - Syuu

which gives the following errors:

$ pacman -Syuu

:: Synchronizing package databases...
git-for-windows is up to date

git-for-windows-mingw32 is up to date

clangarm64 is up to date

mingw32 is up to date

ucrt64 is up to date

clang32 is up to date

clang64 is up to date

msys is up to date

:: Starting core system upgrade...

there is nothing to do

:: Starting full system upgrade...

resolving dependencies...

warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "libcurl"

warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "curl"

warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "libcurl"

:: The following packages cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable
dependencies:
curl  libcurl

Comment: First I would reinstall MSYS2 from scratch just in case. Second, you don't want to install `git` using pacman, since MSYS2's version is laggy. Just use the official git for windows. You can add it to MSYS2's PATH if needed, or just invoke it from Windows shell if the build process doesn't require it.

Comment: Instead of git for windows you might try to use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) instead. In general it gives a closer linux environment experience, and dependencies are easy to install with the setup installer.

Comment: I have Cygwin installed but the script in powershell is telling me to

***** Error running 'bootstrap' command:
Configuration Error: git is configured to use automatic line endings conversion. Please change that by running:
`git config --global core.autocrlf false` inside the MSYS shell

into the MSYS2 terminal which doesn't have git installed. I have used the above command in both powershell and Cygwin but the error still occurs.

Comment: Okay so adding PATH=$PATH':C:\Program Files\Git\bin' seems to have worked for now.

Thank you, much appreciated.